isn't Yudhishtira asking Bhishma TWO questions in the pre-amble to the Vishnu Sahasra Nama?
https://www.swaminarayan.faith/media/3853/vishnu-sahashtra-namavali-stotra-plus-meaninigs.pdf

Kimekam Daivatham Loke, Kim Vapyegam Parayanam,
Sthuvantha Kam Kamarchanda Prapnyur Manava Shubham, 7


Ko Dharma sarva Dharmanam Paramo Matha
Kim Japan Muchyathe Jandur Janma Samsara Bhandanat 8


Yudishtra asked:-
In this wide world , Oh Grandpa,
Which is that one God,
Who is the only shelter?
Who is He whom,
Beings worship and pray,
And get salvation great?
Who is He who should oft,
Be worshipped with love?
Which Dharma is so great,
There is none greater?
And which is to be oft chanted,
To get free.
From these bondage of life, cruel

Yudhistrira is asking for (1) the best prayer and (2) the best dharma.
Bhisma says praying to Vishnu with the VSN is the best prayer.
Is he also presenting the Vishnu Sahasra Nama as a religion(dharma) ?
